# No Matching ABIs when installing on emulator, app has ZERO native code

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to launch an app on the emulator, and my app has zero native code. I'm getting an error on install:

> INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

Any emulator setup should just work for an app with no native code, so I don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your app still has some native libraries inside it: they may come from 3rd party libraries you would be depending on.

Open your APK as a zip file and check inside *./lib* if you really have nothing in here.